# How to filter out NULLs in a Hive query?

Tags: sql, hive

Table is:

[image]

Result should be:

[image]

How can I solve this query?

```
hive\> select \* from xyz;
OK
xyz.col1    xyz.col2    xyz.col3
NULL    b   c
a   NULL    c
a   b   NULL
Time taken: 0.165 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(COL1)AS COL1,MAX(COL2)AS COL2,MAX(COL3)AS COL3
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks sergey its working fine, i didnt know it was so simple. i thought max function can be applied on integers only, didnt know it works for string as well.

Comment: Great ! This is working fine..